# Reversing strings in Java (loops) until "done"

Tags: java

this is a lab for class I'm trying to do. Here's the instructions:
Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:

"Hello there

Hey

done"

the output is:

"ereht olleH

yeH"

And here's what I have right now:

```
public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Type your code here. */
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] inputs = new String[100];
      String input;
      int i = 0;
      while (true) {
         input = scnr.nextLine();
         if(input.equals("Done") || input.equals("done") || input.equals("d"))
            break;
      inputs[i] = input;
      i++;
         }
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         int length = inputs[j].length();
         String reverse = "";
         for (int k = length - i; k >= 0; k--) {
            reverse = reverse + inputs[j].charAt(k);
         }
         System.out.print("\n" + reverse);
      }
   }
}
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VfAg.png)

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you confirm and clarify the example input?  You have "Hello there Hey" but it seems the example input should be "Hey Hello there".

Comment: One comment: the instructions didn't ask you to store 100 strings like you're doing.  You can simply output the string and not store it at all.  It complicates the program needlessly, and will crash if you enter 101 strings.

Comment: Where you have `int k = length - i` that should be `int k = length - 1`.  That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Try to use StringBuilder And use method reverse -- @Artur Todeschini

To add to what Artur said, an ArrayList of StringBuilders could do the trick quite well:

```
for(StringBuilder nextEntry : stringBuilderList)
{
    nextEntry.reverse();
}
```

The enhanced for-loop will go through each entry in the ArrayList, and the StringBuilder's reverse will change the order of the letters.

**EDIT TO SHOW FORMATTING**

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> stringBuilderList= new ArrayList<>();
```

> ***note. given that this is for a lab**, its probably for learning purposes and using built-in classes that does all the work for you are usually not the intended solution. -- @experiment unit 1998X

Comment: note. given that this is for a lab*, its probably for learning purposes and using built-in classes that does all the work for you are usually not the intended solution.

Comment: @experiment unit 1998X has made a very good point here; your professor may not accept this solution. String arrays and ArrayLists filled with StringBuilders are completely different animals.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array, and reverse elements at every index.
This solution is time consuming but does your job

```
 for (int j = 0; j < inputs.lenght; j++) {
     int length = inputs[j].length();
    char a;
    String rev = "";
    for(int i =0; i< length; i++){
        a = inputs[j].charAt(i);
        rev = a + rev;   
    }
     System.out.println(rev);
  }
```

Comment: @Megan, this is definitely closer to what your professor intended based on the code that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use StringBuilder
And use method reverse

Answer (score 0):

This is another "ArrayList and StringBuilder-less" version.
Create two Strings, one filled and one empty:

```
String nextString = stringArray[i], 
    template = new String();
```

Loop through the length of the String, adding the next character in from the end each time through.

```
int length = nextString.length() - 1;
for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
    template += nextString.charAt(length - j);
}
```

Add the whole String to the String array's index

```
stringArray[i] = template;
```

**NOTE**

This is an inner loop for a String array and is NOT complete code

Answer (score 0):

Your print line just needed to be reversed
*System.out.print(reverse + "\n");*

you had  *System.out.print("\n" + reverse);*